# Why is my Javascript function not running from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am facing an issue, where I would like to put my script in another file rather then in my html, but when I put it in my Javascript file, it's not working like before when the script was in the html file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Client-Webapp</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" name="encode" />
  <div id="imgTest"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' href="/ClientApp/www/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {
    console.log('kaksi');
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
        //alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        console.log("Converted Base64 version is: " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

On the console I get nothing. No error or the base64 of the file which is my goal.
I'm making this with Cordova if that's any help.

The file stucture is like this:

```
ClientApp
---www
------index.html
------js
---------index.js
```

Again, it's working if I put the script in the html. So I dont't know if the function calling or the path is the problem or what.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like your script file is not loading. What do you see if you inspect the network tab in your browser’s dev tools? Tip: use relative path in your script src, ie `./js/index.js`

Comment: What you have shown us here is some javascript logic defined within a function - but nowhere in either code block, is the function called.

Comment: href="/ClientApp/www/js/index.js" -> href="js/index.js"

Comment: I used the path you wrote, but still nothing happens. I see nothing in the network tab and console tab either.

Comment: href="js/index.js" is not working either

Comment: as symcbean implies - you haven't *used* the function in the code shown so nothing will show

Comment: Did you run the javascript function?

Comment: Wow, I forgot to change it back before posting my whole problem, thanks for saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using href attribute instead of src in your script tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' href="/ClientApp/www/js/index.js"></script>
```

The type attribute is optional in html5 therefore not really needed here.
Try this:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<script src=“js/index.js”></script>`

Answer (score 0):

i guess u could try out:
`<script src="js/ClientApp/www/js/index.js"></script>`
instead of
`<script type='text/javascript' href="/ClientApp/www/js/index.js"></script>`

i hv replace `href` with `src` and i ignored `type`

`src` has worked for me irrespective of `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: I give the path wrong way that was the problem, changing to `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` and deleting the type of the script was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your script src is not correct.
And you are loading the javascript with `href`. This is wrong. You have to use `src` attribute.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="js/index.js"></script>
```

You can try again.

Have you ran the `encodeImageFileAsURL` javascript function?

Comment: Have you changed the href attribute to src?
And "js/index.js"?

Comment: Without the type attribute it works, and after running the right function, I mistakenly didn't change it back from previous tryings.